# To separate objects detected from an image using PixelLib

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

Consider an image of a bottle. I intend to separate or extract the pixels of the bottle from the image. The bottle is recognized by image segmentation using PixelLib. The code goes as follows:

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation
import cv2

instance_seg = instance_segmentation()
instance_seg.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
segmask, output = instance_seg.segmentImage("sample2.jpg", show_bboxes= True)
cv2.imwrite("img.jpg", output)
```

The 'instance_segmentation' is the class for performing instance segmentation and is imported and an instance of the class is created. 'mask_rcnn_coco.h5' is the mask r-cnn model to perform instance segmentation. 'show_bboxes = True' shows segmentation masks with bounding boxes.

I read the official documentation and there is no mention of how to separate an object detected by PixelLib.

The code is referred from [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-segmentation-with-six-lines-0f-code-acb870a462e8)

Comment: What do you mean by "separate an object"?

Comment: By separation, I meant extracting the pixels that lie in a particular segmentation mask.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can make use of PixelLib to extract a detailed information about each object in an image.
Using this code

```
segmask, output = segment_image.segmentImage("path_to_image", show_bboxes = True)
```

You will obtain the following details:

1. Each object's segmentation mask
2. Each object's bounding box coordinate
3. Each object's corresponding class id

You can then make use of these results in your application.

I am the creator of PixelLib.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Minor note, it's preferable to not add your email address to the answer, since it's not directly related to the answer. Instead, you can add it to your profile page, where users can find it as well.

Comment: @Ayoola...It's a privilege and honor to receive an answer from the creator itself.  It would be of great help to others if you could incorporate this in the official documentation.

Comment: Wish you mentioned the way to obtain the details. When I tried to get a segmentation mask from segmask, I encountered this error: 'TypeError: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar'.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded PixelLib to make it very convenient to extract segmented objects.
Upgrade to the latest version using.

```
pip3 install pixellib --upgrade
```

In this new version of PixelLib I added the feature that makes it possible to filter unused detections and target the segmentation of a specific class.

**Sample Image**
[image: sample].

In the image above we want to extract the bottle object located on the table.
It is possible using this code:

```py
 import pixellib
 from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation
    
 seg = instance_segmentation()
 seg.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
 target_classes = seg.select_target_classes(bottle = True)
 seg.segmentImage("sample_image.jpg", segment_target_classes= target_classes, extract_segmented_objects = True, save_segmented_objects = True, show_bboxes=True,output_image_name="output.jpg")
```

The is very similar to the original code for performing instance segmentation of objects, except the following differences:

- Added the function to choose a target class to segment which is **bottle**.
- We added new parameters to the **segmentImage** function to segment the **target class**, extract the segmented object and save it as a separate image.

**Output Image**
[image]

**Extracted Segmented Object**

[image]

You would do this to access individual values returned by the **segmentImage** function.

```py
segmask, output = seg.segmentImage("sample_image.jpg", segment_target_classes= target_classes, extract_segmented_objects = True, save_segmented_objects = True, show_bboxes=True,output_image_name="output.jpg")
```

Access mask's values using segmask['masks'], bounding box coordinates using segmask['rois'], class ids using segmask['class_ids'] and the extracted  segmented object using segmask['extracted_objects']

Answer (score 0):

In case there is more than one extracted object, the following code

```
segmask, output = seg.segmentImage("sample_image.jpg", extract_segmented_objects = True, save_segmented_objects = True, show_bboxes=True, output_image_name="output.jpg")
```

extracts only the LAST segmented object into segmask['extracted_objects'], i.e. segmask['extracted_objects'] will always contain only ONE object, no matter how many objects the algorithm identified correctly.
I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour, but I wouldn't think so.

It does work, however, if this syntax is used instead:

```
seg.segmentImage("sample_image.jpg", extract_segmented_objects = True, save_segmented_objects = True, show_bboxes=True, output_image_name="output.jpg")
```

In this case the segmented objects are directly written to disk as JPG files and would need to be reloaded to be available for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

[@M. Str](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9873597/m-str) It extracted all the objects in the image, but there is a bug somewhere that fails to return all the objects extracted. I have fixed it and it can now return all the objects extracted from the image.
Upgrade to the latest version of PixelLib using;

```
pip3 install pixellib --upgrade
```

[image: sample image]

```py
import pixellib
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

segment_image = instance_segmentation()
segment_image.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
seg, output = segment_image.segmentImage("sample4.jpg", extract_segmented_objects=True, save_extracted_objects =True,
                                         show_bboxes=True, output_image_name= "a.jpg")
res = seg["extracted_objects"]
for a in res:
    print(a.shape)
```

The printed shapes of the extracted objects in the image.

```
(238, 92, 3)
(174, 260, 3)
(117, 235, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mask [image] like below using this [answer](https://github.com/ayoolaolafenwa/PixelLib/issues/28#issuecomment-1712314277) on github, then remove the background using the following statement.
`bg_removed = cv2.bitwise_and(inp_img, mask)`

[image]